# Initial zero argument in stargazer() removes negative sign

Tags: r, stargazer

Compare the x coefficients in outputs from the stargazer function below. The initial.zero=FALSE argument removes the negative sign. Is this expected?

```
set.seed(1234)
y<-rnorm(1000)
x<- -y+rnorm(1000)
lm<-lm(y~x)
require(stargazer)
stargazer(lm)
stargazer(lm, initial.zero = FALSE)
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Bugs should be reported to the pkg-maintainer. You should get his address with `maintainer('stargazer')`

Comment: Was not sure if it is a bug. I just wrote him.

Comment: Well, I'd be surprised if the author of a formatting program thought that reversing the sign of a negative coefficient wasn't a bug.

Comment: Me too. He's looking into it.